# Drawing logical circuit for a simplified boolean expression

Tags: boolean-expression, boolean-algebra

I need to draw a logical circuit from a simplified boolean expression. 
Here's the expression:

x = PQ'R' + PQ'R + PQR' + PQR

I got the simplified expression as x = P. 
I need to draw the circuit from this simplified expression.

Now, my question is, how to draw the logical circuit when the simplified expression has only one variable?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: I used AND gate and gave both input as P, so it will give the output P itself. Is it right?

Comment: I'm not good with logical circuits but wouldn't `x = P` mean that you essentially have a straight line?

Comment: An AND gate with both inputs driven by P is logically correct, but as @VLAZ said that's more complex than it needs to be.  A wire with no gates is the simplest answer.  In a real circuit there might be reasons to use a gate (your AND with both inputs P, an AND with one input P and the other pulled to 1, and OR with both inputs P, an OR with one input P and the other pulled to 0, gates with Schmitt-trigger inputs, ..) but that's a topic for the [Electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) site, not here.

Answer (score 0):

this is circuit of 'x' that include 4 And gate with three input and 1 Or gate with four input
[image]